# c++ asterisk after the percentage symbol

Tags: c++, c++11, input, user-input, scanf

Following is a piece from my code. I want to input three variables namely c, l and r. But when I remove %*c from the scanf statement, the loop doesn't execute the required number of times and terminates before that. Why is it so? What does %*c do?

```
scanf( "%d", &Q );
    for ( i = 0; i < Q; ++i ) {
        scanf( "%*c%c%d%d", &c, &l, &r );
```

Comment: The answer to "What does this do?" is often readily available in your favourite [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

Answer (score 4):

It's assignment suppression.  From the C11 standard:

> After the %, the following appear in sequence:
>
> - An optional assignment-suppressing character *
>
> ...
>
> Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a *, the result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following the format argument that has not already received a conversion result

So for the case of `"%*c"` a character is read from the stream and discarded (I'd guess that in this application it's discarding newlines).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore an argument - meaning parse it but don't store it - you can put an `*` in the `scanf` string:

`%*d` Parse an integer, but don't store it.
`%*c` Parse a character (any character, not necessarily whitespace), but don't store it.

By deleting `%*c` from `%*c%c`, you don't ignore the first character and assign it to the variable insted.